# what is spring container and bean factory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

What is actually a spring container and bean factory, where it resides ? what is the function of these two ? i went through many explanation but none of the them are understandable

I am learning spring framework. I need a simple and understandable explanation of both spring container and bean factory

Comment: Have you tried reading this [article](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand these things like this:

Imagine you have a magic box called the "Spring Container." This special box is like a home for some special things called "Beans." Now, these beans aren't the ones you eat – they're like little helpers or tools that can do different tasks for you.

The Spring Container is like a manager for these beans. It keeps track of them and takes care of them. Whenever you need a bean to help you with something, you just ask the Spring Container, and it magically gives you the right bean.

Now, let's talk about the "Bean Factory." Think of this as a clever factory where all these beans are created. It's like a place where you design and make different types of beans according to your needs.

So, the Spring Container is like your personal assistant that knows where all the beans are and helps you get them when you need them. And the Bean Factory is like the creative place where these beans are made in the first place.

In simple terms:

Spring Container: Your helpful assistant that gives you the right beans when you ask for them.
Bean Factory: The place where beans are designed and made.
So, when you use the Spring framework, you're using this magic container and factory to make your work easier by getting the right beans to help you out!